# How to use BouncyCastle to generate X509Certificate2 which can be used for WCF authentication?

Tags: c#, wcf, security, x509certificate, bouncycastle

Here's my WCF service code:

```
        ServiceHost svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyClass));

        var tcpbinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential, true);
        //security

        tcpbinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
        svh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new BWUserNamePasswordValidator();
        svh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode =UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
        svh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = GenerateCertificate(myCert);

        svh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyClass), tcpbinding, location);            

        svh.Open();
```

And here's the code, which I'm using to generate the certificate:

```
    static X509Certificate2 GenerateCertificate(string certName)
    {
        var keypairgen = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        keypairgen.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()), 1024));

        var keypair = keypairgen.GenerateKeyPair();

        var gen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

        var CN = new X509Name("CN=" + certName);
        var SN = BigInteger.ProbablePrime(120, new Random());

        gen.SetSerialNumber(SN);
        gen.SetSubjectDN(CN);
        gen.SetIssuerDN(CN);
        gen.SetNotAfter(DateTime.MaxValue);
        gen.SetNotBefore(DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)));
        gen.SetSignatureAlgorithm("MD5WithRSA");
        gen.SetPublicKey(keypair.Public);

        gen.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectKeyIdentifier, false,
                    new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure(keypair.Public));        

        var newCert = gen.Generate(keypair.Private);

        return new X509Certificate2(DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate((Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate)newCert));
    }
```

When I'm starting the server it crashes with following exception:

```
ArgumentException: It is likely that certificate 'CN=MyCert' may not 
have a private key that is capable of key exchange or the process may not have 
access rights for the private key. Please see inner exception for detail.
```

The inner exception is null.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Key pairs used for certificate exchange need to be created explicitly for that purpose. I think you just need to add another extension to your certificate generator like this:

```
gen.AddExtension(
    X509Extensions.KeyUsage, 
    true,
    new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.keyCertSign));
```

Not sure if that syntax is exactly correct but that's the idea: you need to make the key in the certificate as being for certificate signing, and that is a "critical" extension if present.

Comment: added the param. the service still won't start with it.

I was experimenting with creating a workable certificate with makecert, and the correct sequence of commands is 

makecert -n "CN=mfcertificate" -cy authority -a sha1 -sv "nick_ca.pvk" -r "nick_ca.cer"
makecert -pe -n "CN=my Dev" -a sha1 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ic "nick_ca.cer" -iv "nick_ca.pvk" -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -sv "nick_dev.pvk" "nick_dev.cer"
pvk2pfx -pvk "nick_dev.pvk" -spc "nick_dev.cer" -pfx "nick_dev.pfx"

I've got no idea on how to do this in BouncyCastle though

Comment: The error you are getting would be solved using makecert with the "-sky exchange" parameter, I just don't know the BouncyCastle API enough to know how to do that. Sorry.